# org-mode table editor behaves strangely

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, org-table

1. With cursor in row 2, col 3

```
| a | b | c  |
| 1 | 2 | 3 _|
```

2. Pressing `<TAB>` creates a new row:

```
| a | b | c |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
|   |   |   |
```

3. Type more than one character and press tab. Vertical bars have been removed from rows 1 and 2:

[image: table with missing vertical bars]

This isn't the expected behaviour, is it?

Oddly, when I copy and paste from the file into this editor, the bars appear as expected.
Spacemacs version:
0.200.10@25.1.1 (spacemacs)

Org mode version 9.1.5 (9.1.5-1-gb3ddb0-elpaplus @
/home/sweidman/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20171225/)

I tried switching fonts from Source Code Pro to Ubuntu Mono but the
problem persisted.

When I start emacs with "emacs -Q", the problem disappears using org-mode:
Org-mode version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10 @ /usr/local/share/emacs/25.1/lisp/org/)

If I close and re-open the file, the table appears correctly formatted.

Comment: Just wanted to note that the problem does not occur when running the master branch of emacs which gives version GNU Emacs 27.0.50

Answer (score 0):

**I answered my question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38948/org-mode-table-formatting-problem?answertab=active#tab-top) and using it to close this question.**

Steps to fix this issue:

1. I downloaded the latest `org-plus-contrib-yyyymmdd` from [elpa](https://orgmode.org/elpa/).
   The file is available only in `.tar` extension. (Convert that to ZIP
   [online](https://www.zamzar.com/) if you do not have archive program that can handle tar
   extension)
2. I extracted the ZIP archive into
   `C:\Users\path_to\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d` directory and restarted
   emacs.
3. After restart, ran `M-x org-version` and the version had changed to
   `9.1.6` from `9.1.5`

This fixed the table formatting issue. (I'm not a 100% sure of the cause of the problem, but this update fixed things, the way they should be)